# Помогите разобратсья с паттерном Composite (компоновщик) реализация на php

Tags: php, шаблоны-проектирования, компоновщик

```
   class Node
    {
        private $name;
        function __construct($name)
        {
            $this->name = $name;
        }
    }


abstract class Tree
{
    // создает узел (если $parentNode == NULL - корень)
    abstract protected function createNode(Node $node,$parentNode=NULL);
    // удаляет узел и все дочерние узлы
    abstract protected function deleteNode(Node $node);
    // делает один узел дочерним по отношению к другому
    abstract protected function attachNode(Node $node,Node $parent);
    // получает узел по названию
    abstract protected function getNode($nodeName);
    // преобразует дерево со всеми элементами в ассоциативный массив
    abstract protected function export();
}
```

Помогите разобраться с реализацией паттерна Composite (компоновщик)

```
$tree = new TreeComposite();
$tree->createNode(new Node('country'));
$tree->createNode(new Node('UK'),$tree->getNode('country'));
$tree->createNode(new Node('RU'),$tree->getNode('country'));
$tree->createNode(new Node('msk'),$tree->getNode('RU'));
$tree->createNode(new Node('sub'),$tree->getNode('RU'));
```

Comment: в чем собственно вопрос ?

Comment: вопрос по методу getNode($nodeName)
Насколько я понял нужно рекурсивно искать ключ ($nodeName) в массиве $tree->nodes или тут другая логика должна быть ?

Comment: ну если у вас там многомерный массив без внешнего индекса ,то да нужно будет перебрать массив что бы получить нужный id . Но как это относится к композиту ?